# Unable to set shared library path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

My project invlolves calling a java function from C and vice versa. Hence I have used JNI. It works perfectly when I compile it from terminal. But I am facing problem when I try to use the same java file in eclipse IDE. I have tried to cmpile it in eclipse using a default package. It works perfectly. But the problem arises when I put in a package and then compile. I am getting the following error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no my in java.library.path

For loading the shared library I have used the following command in java file

System.loadLibrary("my");

"libmy.so" is the name of the shared library which I generated from the terminal and is trying to use in eclipse

Comment: maybe you can try passing it as a VM argument. Something like -Djava.library.path=PATH_TO_LIB . I had a same problem with a MS JDBC .dll and i solved it this way. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to alter your eclipse run configuration for the program that is trying to use the shared library.

Try adding  `-Djava.library.path=/path/to/your/libary.so` to the JVM arguments on the launcher